# Changing the core data model versionIdentifier

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, mapping-model, core-data-migration

I'm trying to debug an issue with my mapping model not being used by my migration, and so I printed out the sourceModel and destinationModel's versionIdentifiers, but both were blank.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectModel/versionIdentifiers

This link says to set them in the model inspector but I can't find that on xcode 3 or 4... or at least there is no versionIdentifier or similar in anywhere I can find for the data model itself.

Does anyone know where I find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this posting - and, in particular, my answer ;) : [Core Data lightweight migration: Can't find or automatically infer mapping model for migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011807/core-data-lightweight-migration-cant-find-or-automatically-infer-mapping-model)

I did not find versionIdentifiers to be as helpful in debugging as the 'metadata' for the various entities - as I outlined here: [NSManagedObjectModel versionIdentifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895156/nsmanagedobjectmodel-versionidentifiers)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried your suggestion fr the versionidentifier setting the other day (doing get info 2x) but it never worked for me. The same window always showed up. Thanks anyways, i've solved my issue another way (so i no longer need to debug it).