# Get name of current core data model

Tags: ios, core-data

I have made some changes to my `Core Data` model, and the we are handling the migration as described here:  [Lightweight Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html).

That's not a problem. However, I want to make a couple of other updates to my data that are conditional on the current model version. How can I get the name of the current model version? I expected to see something like:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] currentDataModelName]
```

but I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask your `NSManagedObjectModel` by sending `versionIdentifiers` to the receiver.

```
- (NSSet *)versionIdentifiers
```

The docu is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003610)

Comment: This works, but it's worth noting that version identifiers is empty by default, as noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895156/nsmanagedobjectmodel-versionidentifiers, and in the documentation, so in order to determine if the model had changed, I had to manually set versionIdentifiers for the objectModel, then compare it to a value stored elsewhere (e.g. NSUserDefaults).

Answer (score 7):

You can get the model name and use it instead of model identifier. Check out this excellent article [Custom Core Data Migrations](http://www.objc.io/issue-4/core-data-migration.html) and the corresponding [Github code](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-core-data-migration). With the help of the NSManagedObjectModel+MHWAdditions category you can retrieve the model name.

- [NSManagedObjectModel+MHWAdditions.h](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-core-data-migration/blob/master/BookMigration/NSManagedObjectModel%2BMHWAdditions.h)
- [NSManagedObjectModel+MHWAdditions.m](https://github.com/objcio/issue-4-core-data-migration/blob/master/BookMigration/NSManagedObjectModel%2BMHWAdditions.m)

**Source model** name:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *storeType = ...;
NSURL *storeURL = ...;
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator  metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:storeType
                                                                                           URL:storeURL
                                                                                         error:&error];
NSManagedObjectModel *sourceModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:@[[NSBundle mainBundle]]
                                                                forStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
NSString *sourceModelName = [sourceModel mhw_modelName];
```

**Destination model** name:

```
NSString *destinationModelName = [[self managedObjectModel] mhw_modelName];
```

Assuming you implemented a `managedModelObject` getter. If not, here is out-of-the-box implementation.

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSString *momPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourModel" ofType:@"momd"];

    if (!momPath) {
        momPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YourModel" ofType:@"mom"];
    }

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:momPath];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}
```

When migrating, the source model name and destination model name will differ. Otherwise, the names will be the same.